# How to change analytics tracking ID on Google Developers in the app configuratiion file

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services

I was trying to enable google analytics and get the configuration file for my android app from [google developers](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add), but I accidentally chose the wrong trakcing ID for google analytics as we have multiple tracking IDs. I can't find where I can change it neither a place to disable google analytics service.
[screenshot from Google Developers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phy8o.png)

It is said that the services will be added to Google Developer Console but I can only find a list of APIs that are enabled.

Could somebody tell me how I may modify the configuration so I can download the correct configuration file for my android app?

Comment: One quick workaround might be to just open up the downloaded file and change the tracking ID in the file: `sed -i "s/UA-BADTRACKINGID-1/UA-GOODTRACKINGID-2/g"`

Comment: that's what i did for now... but still want a solution to this so that I won't use the wrong file in the future if I have to download the file again to enable other google play services

Answer (score 1):

A Google Analytics tracking ID is only associated with a project in the `google-services.json` file that you download. Services could have been added to your project, but it may have only been Google Cloud Messaging and Google+ API.

To change the tracking ID used you can either

a) Change the tracking ID in `google-services.json`. The property containing the tracking ID is clearly named: `tracking_id`, or

b) go back to the [web site](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add) to recreate and download a new `google-services.json` file.

Comment: how can I recreate? by creating a new project?

Comment: Visit https://developers.google.com/mobile/add to go through the file creation process again.

Answer (score 0):

The tracking id exists in the `google-services.json` but you can always change it according to your needs.

I assume you want to different your ***production and development builds*** hit points. Just create two properties in Google Analytics Dashboard and use them like this:

```
GoogleAnalytics googleAnalytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(application
                                  .getApplicationContext());
googleAnalyticsTracker = googleAnalytics.newTracker(BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE
                               .equals("release")?"UA-XXXXXXX":"UA-YYYYYYY");
```

*** while initializing your application class**